# Concept of a subring in Atiyah-Macdonald's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

[image]

I think this definition is wrong, because nothing guarantees that the subring is closed to additive inverses.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I quite understand why you think his definition is wrong...

Comment: @RobertAuffarth: The definition seems to imply that $\mathbb N$ is a "subring" of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Oh! Now I understand, thanks.

Comment: Yep, seems like a problem. What edition of the book are you looking at? A "hack" fix would be to change it to: "and contains the additive inverse of the identity element of $A$." But better to just assert that $S$ is an additive subgroup.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think it's the first one from 1969.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews are there another ones?

Comment: For some reason, I thought there was a later edition, but looking around, I didn't find one. @user42912

Comment: How about the following modification?

 "$S$ is closed under addition and multiplication, *under which it is a ring*, and contains the identity element of $A$."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is a typo. In Russian translation of the book it is written: "... if $S$ is an additive subgroup, closed under multiplication ..."

Comment: Clever guys the Russians. The mistake went through in the Spanish translation :)

Comment: @Adrián Barquero No, not all Russians are clever. :-) The book was translated by Yu.Manin.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot believe that the definition of a subring in Atiyah-Macdonald is wrong or incomplete. I still try to find a way to read the definition so that it becomes true ;-).

By the way, instead of adding "if $S$ is an additive subgroup ...", it suffices to demand that $-1 \in S$. Because then we have $-x = (-1) \cdot x \in S$ for all $x \in S$.

By the way, even then this won't be the "correct" definition: A subring is not just a subset with properties. It is a subset with extra structure, namely a *ring*, and properties. A quite abstract definition would be: A subring of $R$ is a subobject of $R$ in the category of rings. Equivalently, and more explicit: A subring $S$ of $R$ is a ring (!) together with a homomorphism of rings $S \to R$, which is just an inclusion on the underlying sets. But in practice these are often just injective maps, not inclusions in the sense of set theory (for example, $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[T]$). The category-theoretic definition might be abstract, but it is really useful in practice. Even abstract algebra texts such as the one by Atiyah-Macdonald use it without any explanation. So their definition of a subring is not just wrong because the closure under additive inverses is lacking, but also because this is not the definition which is used in the book.